# What does it mean to say: "It's no longer 2005"?

Tags: meaning

Is this an English phrase or a major event in the IT industry? If it is the latter, please let me know what is all about?

> **It’s no longer 2005**
>   As in the offline world, legislators must strike a balance between security and liberty. Especially after attacks, when governments want to be seen to act, they may be tempted to impose blanket bans on speech. Instead, they should set out to be clear and narrow about what is illegal—which will also help platforms deal with posts quickly and consistently. Even then, the threshold between free speech and incitement will be hard to define. The aim should be to translate offline legal norms into the cyber domain.

[Terror and the internet: Tech firms could do more to help stop the jihadists](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21723110-legal-restrictions-must-be-proportionate-and-thought-through-tech-firms-could-do-more-help), the 10 June 2017 issue of *The Economist*

Comment: Is this about the end of support for Microsoft SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Times have changed. Something that might have been appropriate in 2005 isn't appropriate any longer.

Comment: As _The Economist_ is a British newspaper, the reference, given the context of "security and liberty", is presumably to the 7th July 2005 London bombings.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently it's a reference to the 2005 US Criminal Copyright law which prohibits the unacknowleged use of another intellectual's property for the purpose of financial gain. An example of the laws limiting internet freedom to fight against criminality.